# Using external custom CSS with Notify.js jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, styling

I am just beginning to learn jQuery and CSS and have a question regarding styling toasts/notifications that are generated using a specific jQuery plugin **[Notify.js](http://notifyjs.com/)**.

There is documentation on the plugins website but I can not properly understand how to limit the amount of code in my JS-file concerning the styling and instead keep it in my external CSS file. It seems you should just be able to use the right naming conventions for your CSS classes and then be good to go in some simple way.

So instead of

```
$.notify.addStyle('check', {
    html : "<div><span data-notify-text/></div>",
    classes : {
        base : {
        "white-space" : "nowrap",
        "background-color" : "#cccccc",
        "padding" : "5px",
        "font-family" : "Comic Sans MS"
        },
        uncheck : {
            "color" : "white",
            "background-color" : "#252525"
        }
    }
});
```

I'd like to use something like this in my external CSS-file

```
.notifyjs-check-base { 
white-space: nowrap; 
background-color: #D3D3D3;/*lightgray*/ 
padding: 5px; 
font-family: Comic Sans MS;  }

.notifyjs-check-uncheck{
color: white,
background-color: #252525;}
```

And then just have something like

```
$.notify.addStyle('check');
```

in my js file to use a style on my notification.

All of this is used within a Chrome Extension to display messages to the user.

How would you do it? Make todays good deed and help a beginner :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, I guess you want to seperate your javascript and css code. Then you can write up to this in your javascript file.

```
 $.notify.addStyle('foo', {
    html:
      "<div>" +
        "<div class='clearfix'>" +
          "<div class='title' data-notify-html='title'/>" +
          "<div class='buttons'>" +
            "<button class='no'>Cancel</button>" +
            "<button class='yes' data-notify-text='button'></button>" +
          "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
      "</div>"
});
```

and rest of the css classes in external css file

```
.notifyjs-foo-base {
 opacity: 1;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #DFF0D8;
 color:#468847;
 border-color:#D6E9C6;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.notifyjs-foo-base .title {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.notifyjs-foo-base .buttons {
  width: 70px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.notifyjs-foo-base button {
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 60px;
}
```